# Prove a group that has a normal subgroup isomorphic to $D_8$ has a non-trivial center

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, dihedral-groups

> Let $G$ be a group which has a normal subgroup isomorphic to $D_8$. Prove that $G$ has a non trivial center.

So, given $g\in G$, $h\in D_8$ $ghg^{-1}\in D_8$. So I tried to prove that there is an element (not equal the identity) $h\in D_8$ such that $ghg^{-1}=h$, but no success so far. I used trial and error method. But did not try all because there are lot. My question is, is it possible to find such element? Or else what other method works here?

Comment: The first step is to realize that $D_8$ has non-trivial center. Prove this first. (Although this does not imply yet the claim.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: if $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, and $|N|=2$, then $N \subseteq Z(G)$.

Comment: Great answer! thanks.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 5):

Note that the centre of a group $D_8$  is a *characteristic* subgroup of $D_8$.
Hence *any* automorphism of $D_8$ (e.g., those that are inner automorphisms of $G$) leave it invariant. Hence you should determine the centre  of $D_8$ itself - and then verify that it has only few automorphisms.